# Yarn install Fails with exit code 127

Tags: yarn-v2

Yarn install Fails with the error 'Command failed with exit code 127.'
I tried npm install and it works fine, I have yarn.lock and yarn install should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are some remains of nodemodules. This might be caused because of accidentally hitting npm install and stopping it in between, as this would create some incomplete nodemodules, this cause yarn install to fail with exit code 127.